# Sci fi story featuring young faced immortals fighting galactic clones

Tags: story-identification

I've asked this on other sites but nobody seems to remember the book.

This is one I think i read in the nineties. Humanity has very long lives and over the centuries society has changed. They opt for prolongation in mid puberty so everyone now appears to be like 14 or 15 but really several centuries old.

Space navy has senior admirals and raw recruit school leavers looking the same age.

Biggest enemy of humanity is a clone brotherhood out in the galaxy who are gradually taking over all man's worlds.

Protagonist is a heroic naval officer who, we learn early on, is deemed untrustworthy cos he is one of the clones but was raised by the goodies.

The clones occasionally do face on space battles but a lot of time they infiltrate planets and stealthily set up like monastic houses all over. They then raise clones until they outnumber the norms.

One trait is a cult of no personality, if you pick a red shirt from laundry piles then you are called Red for the day (or Blue / Green etc)

The goodies have an option called seclusion or reclusion when they get tired of centuries of strife against the clones. They stop taking immortality drugs and age and die normally.

Clones are getting nearer star system by star system to earth so naval hero goes on a long trek with his battle fleet to slow them down, he has some meetings with the clones, all with his face.

The navy he is in has a hierarchy reminiscent of the Nicholas Seafort books but all baby-faced.

I've done searches and Clone Brothers / Brotherhood in book titles gives a lot of results, I've gone through all these at various times but none are relevant

Somebody was looking for it in SFF Chronicles and I added onto his post hoping it might help some kind person to solve it for us both - No luck but a tad more info

https://www.sffchronicles.com/threads/2448/

Comment: You might want to mention a bunch of the books that you've already excluded; http://www.sffworld.com/forum/threads/clone-brotherhood-immortal-mankind-far-future-book-search.51621/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hero!* by Dave Duncan

> Vaun, born a peasant in the stinking mud flats of Ult, a thriving
>   colony planet, claws his way to survival and fame by becoming the
>   toughest young officer in the Space Patrol. A veteran of the brutal
>   training academy, he seizes opportunities as they arise, leading the
>   first ship out against a surprise attack by the mysterious
>   Brotherhood. He returns to a hero’s welcome as the Brotherhood ship
>   falls to the surface of his home planet in shattered pieces. The
>   Brotherhood is elsewhere unstoppable, though, as neighboring planets,
>   one by one, fall silent, conquered. And then, the Patrol detects a
>   huge spacecraft launched from one of the now‑silent worlds and headed
>   for Ult. Facing a challenge greater than he can truly hope to
>   overcome, Vaun nonetheless sets out to save Ult for a second time.

http://www.daveduncan.com/books/hero/

From [goodreads review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/1104355?book_show_action=true):

> A military hero struggles with his identity as a clone when he’s
>   caught between in a war between humans and the Brotherhood who created
>   him.

Comment: Yes! At last my search has been answered. It is indeed Hero by Dave Duncan. Thank you (now I gotta go other sites and update this question)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have elements similar to some of [Joe Haldeman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Haldeman)'s work.   You should look at the *Forever War* and *Forever Peace* series, and *Buying Time*.   Although it doesn't seem a perfect fit, I've only read a few of them (and long ago), so it could be one of his other works.

Comment: No sorry. Thanks for trying. I've read all the Joe Haldeman and definitely not them